# Downloading pdf in angular server

Tags: angular, pdf, backend, jspdf

Firstly I'll describe the proccess so far. I use jspdf in my angular frontend, and once I have the pdf I need to send it to my backend and download it in the server which holds it. So far I tried a lot of differnet options and none of them seem to be working. Firstly I send the pdf object through the angular router, but it was too big, so not all the data was send. I changed the size of the data allowed but it didn't seem to work. if you want code about it I'll upload it but that's not my main point. After that I created both a blob object and the base64 pdf and sent them to the server, and they show completelly and right. However I don't want to show the pdf, I just want to download it. Most answers I've seen so far include document or window, which I cannot use because I just need to download it. Any answer for the blob or base64 conversion to pdf and download would be fine. I upload the code of the base64 which is the last one I was trying from the server side, even though there is not much code as I wasn't able to find any solution, but for you to see the format:

```
public async sendemail (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<any> {
var base64=req.body.base64;
console.log(base64);
}
```

From here on I need to download the base64 file in pdf. Thanks.

Comment: you can use filesaver

Comment: but that uses a browser, and I have no browser, I just want to download it

Answer (score 0):

This modification to your function uses the new(ish) fetch api to get the base64 image as a blob and then download it.

```
public async sendemail (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<any> {
    var base64=req.body.base64;

    fetch("data:image/png;base64," + base64)
        .then(res => res.blob())
        .then(blob => {
            if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, "download.pdf");
            } else {
                const link = document.createElement("a");
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download = "download.pdf";
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
            }
        });
}
```